# No module named 'tabulate' when running from cmd

Tags: python, conda, tabulate

I use a conda environment called tf that has all necessary packages installed.
If I run the python file in cmd I get the following error:

[image: error]

I reinstalled the package multiple times but it did not make any difference.
However if I run my file from PyCharm (that also uses the tf conda environment) it works without problems. How is that even possible?

[image: pycharm]

Comment: What is `start_gui.py`?  Is it using the correct python interpreter?

Comment: Yes. As I already mentioned it works fine in PyCharm. So nothing is wrong with this file

Comment: What does `python start_gui.py` do? Perhaps Windows is running Python scripts through a system-default interpreter rather than the `python` that is prioritized on PATH (i.e., the one in the **tf** Conda env).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using `conda install -c conda-forge tabulate`?

If this doesn't work, you can try 3 other options through this link: https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/tabulate